# what is the correct way of doing a many-to-many self-referencing relationship in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following active record models:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'follower_id'  
end  

class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :relationships  
  has_many :followers, :through => :relationships  
end
```

I get an error when I try user.followers.
    ArgumentError: Unknown key(s): identifier
    from /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib      /active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:43:in `assert_valid_keys'

Comment: You would get that error if one of your keys in your hash were "identifier"... is there code you're not showing us where identifier is mentioned?

Comment: Thanks @ryan.  I took out the :identifier column and watched ryanb's rails cast #163 and it finally works.  http://media.railscasts.com/videos/163_self_referential_association.mov